# Most efficient way to map list[list[str]] to two lists of keys and values in python?

Tags: python

For `input` (`list[list[str]]`), what is the most efficient/pythonic way to generate a dictionary or two lists of unique keys and all values?

Example:

```
input = [["key_1", "value_1"], ["key_1", "value_2"], ["key_1", "value_3"], ["key_1", "value_4"], ["key_2", "value_5"], ["key_2", "value_6"]]

return {"key_1": ["value_1", "value_2", "value_3", "value_4"], "key_2": ["value_5", "value_6"]}

or

return ([["key_1", "key_2"], [["value_1", "value_2", "value_3", "value_4"], ["value_5", "value_6"]])
```

Comment: What have you tried? See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple one-pass loop with `.setdefault` to create a list for each new key encountered:

```
i=[["key_1", "value_1"], ["key_1", "value_2"], ["key_1", "value_3"], ["key_1", "value_4"], ["key_2", "value_5"], ["key_2", "value_6"]]

result={}
for sl in i:
    result.setdefault(sl[0], []).append(sl[1])

>>> result
{'key_1': ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4'], 'key_2': ['value_5', 'value_6']}
```

If you actually want the second result:

```
>>> list(zip(*result.items()))
[('key_1', 'key_2'), (['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4'], ['value_5', 'value_6'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
#Input, warning dont use Keywords as varible
inp = [["key_1", "value_1"], ["key_1", "value_2"], ["key_1", "value_3"], ["key_1", "value_4"], ["key_2", "value_5"], ["key_2", "value_6"]]

#Creating dictionary with key with value  empty list 
dic = {i[0]:[]  for i in inp}    # output {'key_1': [], 'key_2': []}

#Append that all value in that empty list with the respect of key
[dic[i[0]].append(i[1]) for i in inp] 

#display
dic
```

Output:

```
{'key_1': ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4'],
 'key_2': ['value_5', 'value_6']}
```

creating list using above dictionary:

```
[list(dic.keys()), list(dic.values())]

#Output
[['key_1', 'key_2'],
 [['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4'], ['value_5', 'value_6']]]
```

Try to achieve second output without dictionary:

```
keys = list(set([i[0] for i in inp]))    #['key_2', 'key_1']

values = [[] for k in keys]              #[[],[]] 

[values[keys.index(i[0])].append(i[1]) for i in inp]

[keys, values]

#Output

 [['key_2', 'key_1'],
 [['value_5', 'value_6'], ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4']]]
```

Comment: These are all bad methods with potentially geometric complexity. Your last example is traversing the list 3 times. There are easy 1 pass solutions that have O n complexity. Use those.